# Access Azure Key Vault

Tags: delphi, azure-keyvault

Is there a way to access the Azure Key Vault using Delphi?  I can access a database and blob storage with the Data.Cloud.AzureAPI unit in Berlin but want to get the database connection string from the Key Vault and can't seem to find any code out there that is doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in the product itself supporting Azure Key Vault. Using the REST client library you should be able to access that API, but making sure you apply the proper authentication strategy -- which might not be trivial.